# How to use Laravel to Update of a table record using POST method

Tags: php, crud, laravel-5.4

We are doing a feature in laravel, which involves display of a list (user list) in a laravel view.  The userlist comes with one user in a row in a tabular format.  Each user can be either edited or deleted.

Then we proceed to select one of the users for an edit.  This is done by doing a form submit using method = "GET".  The user details gets displayed in a second page.  We do the entry in this page and submit.  If there are no errors in validation the update goes through successfully.  If there are errors in validation the error message gets displayed in the same view (user details page).

However, the GET method displays the value in the URL which we want to avoid.  When we use the POST method, and there are validation errors the operation returns an error.  We are trying to figure out how to use POST method instead of GET method in the first screen.  Can somebody help on this ?  Or plain help on a CRUD example for update of a table without using GET method for any form submit, purely using POST methods ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you please add what errors you are getting with action post ?

Comment: There are quite a few steps involved including making sure you have the right routes, controllers, actions etc. Take a look at a tutorial and post back here if you run into a specific error: https://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-laravel-crud-with-resource-controllers

Comment: display error message https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAAUN.png

Comment: add your code instead of a image